# Android C++ how to read library installed at os level

Tags: android, android-ndk, java-native-interface, native

For security reason, I want to read jni library installed at the OS level from the same library within the package. This is to check by comparing checksum whether installed library at the OS level is same as the library in the apk. This is ensure no malicious library was replaced by rooting device.

Any C++ code you suggest?

Comment: That's not going to do what you think it will.  Do you think every device has the same version of every library?  They'll be on slightly different patch versions, compiled with different options, different optimizations.  The OS version may even be newer if your phone has gotten a security update.  The odds that some version of the library you compile and put in your app is going to match what's in the system library is basically 0.  If you want to use your own version, just do that.  The time checking if the library is changed is wasted effort, as its not a static version you can compare to.

Comment: Also, if they can root the device-  they can just go ahead and overwrite the version of the .so file in your app, so its a moot point anyway